# What is a branch taken stall?

Tags: assembly, branch, mips

I'm analyzing a simple assembly program with Winmips64 and in one moment the program has a branch taken stall, but I don't know why and what type of stall it is. I have been searching on Internet and I found something related with "prediction stalls", but I didn't understand it.

In the picture you can see one of the moment when a branch taken stall is produced.

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A branch taken stall is a stall when a branch is taken :-)

The core reason for this [Instruction prefetch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_prefetch), where multiple instructions in a stream are processed in parallel. See also [pipeline picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cb/Pipeline%2C_4_stage.svg)

In the simplest form, while instruction n in a stream is executing, the next (n+1) is already decoding. The machine thus executes one instruction ever clock on average, but in reality an instruction takes two clock (one clock decode, one clock execute).  This principle can be split up in more stages. (like e.g. effect address calculation, and stages related to register renaming) The Netburst architecture (Pentium 4/D) was notorious for having very deep pipelines. (and thus horrible penalties if something was mispredicted)

In the simple two stage case, if you branch (go to a different instruction than the next), the instruction on the target address hasn't decoded yet. Therefore it must be decoded first, and thus the execution of this instruction takes two clocks. This extra clock is the branch stall penalty.

More modern CPUs try to minimize these penalties by [guestimating possible branch targets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_prediction)  as early as possible and already prefetch their instructions speculatively. To maximize the chance that a branch is prefetched properly they also [calculate the chance that a branch is taken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_target_predictor)